# keycloak internal server error when accessing token url

Tags: keycloak

I ran the keycloak instance by

```
docker run -d --name keycloak \
 -e ROOT_LOGLEVEL=INFO \
 -e KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=INFO \
 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin \
 -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin \
 -p 8080:8080 \
 -it jboss/keycloak:master -b 0.0.0.0

docker logs -f keycloak
```

And then visit http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token, get Internal Server Error:

[image]

So,

1. How to get the error log? `docker logs keycloak` stays at the startup information, now new request log.
2. Where is wrong, and how to fix the internal server error?

---

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you need GET request `/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token`?

Token endpoint is for POST requests, not for GET request - see OIDC spec https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#TokenRequest

Comment: Thats true,  but Keycloak should return the correct http status 405 "Method not allowed". Also when the url is incorrect, you sometimes get Cors errors, which are also misleading. SOO annoying.